# Default frame around theorems in amsart

Tags: amsmath, mdframed, amsart

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
    \begin{definition}
        badsfhadsgufeiklufheiuwfhkusbadf
    \end{definition}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to make the frame default, i.e. to include it in the preamble such that every definition, theorem etc. has a frame by default?

Comment: Are you sticking to `mdframed`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not necessarily, this is just the one I used to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcolorbox` either provides its own highly configurable framed `theorem` environments or wraps around existing environment using `\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{some options}`, where `definition` is the environment defined as in the OP.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{enhanced jigsaw,colback={white!40!yellow}, colframe=red,boxrule=2pt, sharp corners}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within={section}]{Definition}{Definition}{enhanced jigsaw,colback={white!40!yellow}, colframe=blue,boxrule=2pt, sharp corners}{def:}


\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{definition}
  badsfhadsgufeiklufheiuwfhkusbadf
\end{definition}

\begin{Definition}{My tcolorbox theorem}{exampleone}
  badsfhadsgufeiklufheiuwfhkusbadf
\end{Definition}


\end{document}
```

[image]

A generic interface for defining theorems:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newframedtheorem}{O{}momo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]}%
    }
   {\newtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}}
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#2}{#1}%
}

\newframedtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newframedtheorem[
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback={white!40!yellow},
  colframe=red,
  boxrule=2pt,
  sharp corners,
]{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{theorem}[Important]
Something neat to state.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Dull]
Something neat to define.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

The `\newframedtheorem` environment has an initial optional argument for the frame options (see `definition`) and then the usual arguments for `\newtheorem`. It obeys the usual style settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast respones. I somehow get an undefined control sequence error using `\tcolorboxenvironment`, but as far as I can see the package is installed.

Comment: Do you have a reasonably newer version of `tcolorbox` installed? Current version is 3.9, but I think the command is available for at least 1 year, so most likely down to versions 3.20 etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `thmtools` package, which has a `mdframed` key to define new theorems. For a simple frame with background color, I defined a `framed` key, so one can use the `framed` environment, from the `framed` package.  It can break across pages.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed,  etoolbox}
  \colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %

\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame]{definition}
\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
    \begin{definition}
        badsfhadsgufeiklufheiuwfhkusbadf
    \end{definition}

    \begin{proposition}
        badsfhadsgufeiklufheiuwfhkusbadf
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]