# How to use continuous numbering in different theorems?

Tags: numbering

I have two newtheorems named "remark" & "remarks". I want to make them use the same numbering, something like:

> Remark 1:
>   tatatatatata
>
> Remarks 2:
>   blabblalalba
>
> Remarks 3:
>
> Remark 4:

---

This is what i am using in my code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{theoremddq}% name of the style to be used  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem   
{2mm}%measure of space to indent   
{\bfseries}% name of head font   
{}%punctuation between head and body   
{ }% space after theorem head; " "= normal interword space   
{\underline{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}:} {\underline{\thmnote{\textit{(#3)}}}} }

\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{remark*}{Remarque}

\theoremstyle{theoremdd}

\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{remarks*}{Remarques}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which theorem-related packages you load in the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you need to add the optional argument to your theorem declaration to indicate they should use the same number system.

This means adding `[remark*]` to your `\newframedtheorem` command for `remarks*` like so:

```
\newframedtheorem[...]{remarks*}[remark*]{Remarques}
```

Here's a working example, borrowing some of the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346393/64265):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newframedtheorem}{O{}momo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]}%
    }
   {\newtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}}
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#2}{#1}%
}

\newtheoremstyle{theoremddq}% name of the style to be used  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem   
{2mm}%measure of space to indent   
{\bfseries}% name of head font   
{}%punctuation between head and body   
{ }% space after theorem head; " "= normal interword space   
{\underline{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}:} {\underline{\thmnote{\textit{(#3)}}}} }

\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{remark*}{Remarque}

\theoremstyle{theoremddq}

\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{remarks*}[remark*]{Remarques}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark*} Remark here. \end{remark*}
\begin{remarks*} Some remarks. \end{remarks*}
\begin{remarks*} Some more remarks. \end{remarks*}
\begin{remark*} Another remark. \end{remark*}

\end{document}
```

[image: latex output showing continuous numbering]

Comment: Thank you :D Mr Zac

Comment: I think there are some spurious spaces in the second box.